# ExifTool code use for setting image description

Tags: exiftool

With [ExifTool](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/) I would create the field using ImageDescription IPCT Headeline + Caption abstract-but it always fails. The command you use:

```
exiftool "-exif: ImageDescription <IPTC: caption-abstract" "-IPTC: eheadline <headlineline" -r -P -progress.
```

I can Correct the string.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're asking. Are you trying to copy IPTC:Headline and IPTC:Caption-Abstract into Exif:ImageDescription? What is the command that you're currently trying to use?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I would copy IPCT Headline (eg Lugano) + IPCT Captio (Sandro example) in EXIF Description.Il command use
exiftool "-exif: ImageDescription <IPTC: Caption-Abstract" -r -P --progress
copy only IPCT Caption.copia Caption only and do not know how to do.
If possible it would create two lines of exif Descrition
 example
 Lugano
 Sandro.
 I apologize for my English but I'm speaking Italian
 Thank you for your help

 Sandro